# Samba Share on remote machine

Tags: storage, samba, nfs, share, sshfs

I'm with the following environment:
I have 3 computers: A machine working as a storage (Ubuntu 14.04) (Khan), a Samba Server (Ubuntu 14.04 with Samba 4.3.9 with a NT4-like Domain) (Vader) and a Windows 7 machine with network access to both machines (SkyWalker).

What is my objective: I want to make a folder on Khan browseable as a Samba Share to SkyWalker.

What I have already tried: I tried to mount Khan's folder on Vader using "sshfs -o allow_others  " and editing fuse.conf on Vader to allow user_allow_others. Then adding the Samba Share to the smb.conf file. It becomes browseable, but as I believe Samba is using the UNIX permissions mapping, I don't have permission to access this folder, as my user and group in the samba server doesn't exists on Khan.

I know there are easier ways like making SkyWalker access Khan directly through sshfs, but what I basically need is to make a folder in other machine be completely accessible to the samba server and let the samba server handle the permissions in the files (like with force group, valid_users, etc)

It doesn't really need to be done with SSHFS, it can be done with other filesystems like NFS. I just don't want to sync my user and group lists in both machines.

Following is my smb.conf share configuration:

```
[khan_test]
        comment = /opt/teste folder on Khan
        path = /khan_teste
        valid users = +IT
        write list = +IT
        force group = IT
        browseable = no
        read only = no
```

Thank you for your time.